# What is the meaning of daimond bracket in java generics containg two types List<car<u>>

Tags: java, generics

Whats is `List<Car<U>>`?,what is the meaning of two parameters inside the List?Am new to generics and this the example code i picked it online...Explain pls!

```
package generics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Car<T>{
    private T t;

    public T getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setT(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}
public class CarList{
    public static <U> void addCar(U u, List<Car<U>> cars){
        //Whats is List<Car<U>>?,what is the meaning of two parameters inside the List?

        Car<U> car=new Car<>();

        car.setT(u);
        //Could someone expalin the above code

        cars.add(car);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Car<String>> carlist=new ArrayList<>();
        CarList.addCar("Audi", carlist);
    }
}
```

Comment: You tagged the answer. Google it.

Comment: In generics `U` in `List<Car<U>>` is a type placeholder. This means you can use any type in place of `U`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First have a look at the Car class, it allows you to generalize the class and set/ get something of the same type to that class. Imagine (it is maybe a bad exmaple) you would want to set your cars an Engine. Since different Engines work in a different way (gas, diesel, a mule pulling the car) but all make a Car "start" you would want to have a Interface to later have concrete implementations of your gas, diesel and mullet-Engines:

```
interface Engine{
    public void start();
}
```

And say a first "implementation" of above Interface:

```
class GasEngine implements Engine{
    public void start(){
        // check if enoth fuel available
        // start ignition
        // etc. etc. 
    }
}
```

Since your Car-Class was defined with generics a first example would be interpreted as this:

```
public class TestMe{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // You just create "a Car" without any more information
        Car car = new Car();
        // Since there was no additional Information you can apply anything to that Car
        car.setT("Anything");
        car.setT(new Integer(5));

        // You create a Car "bound" to the Engine-Interface
        Car<Engine> carGeneral = new Car<Engine>();

        // So only references that are implementing the Engine-Interface can be set to this car
        GasEngine myGasEngine = new GasEngine();
        carGeneral.setT(myGasEngine);

        // While this wont compile:
        // carGeneral.setT("Anything");

        // Also note your car is not an Engine!!!
        System.out.println("A Car is an Engine, true of false? -> "+ (carGeneral instanceof Engine));

    }
}
```

Now we are at the point i feared, my example is bad because i have absolutly no idear on what 'U' could be to give this code any sence (i thought about a car-type first?...).

Lets make a minimal change and say your method is not called 'addCar' but 'createCarWithEngineAndAddToCarList'. In that case it would look like this:

```
class CarList{
public static <U> void createCarWithEngineAndAddToCarList(U u, List<Car<U>> cars){

    /* Q: Whats is List<Car<U>>?,what is the meaning of two parameters inside the List?
     * 
     * A: "They define the List cars is only able to hold objects of the Type <Car<U>>"
     * 
     * A: At this point we know:
     * 
     *    - cars is of type List (has Methods such as 'add')
     *    - cars contains Objects of Type Car<U>
     *      => No matter what we take out of that list, it will be of type Car<U>
     *    - The type <U> is not yet known and be defined at runtime
     */

    // We create a new Car-Object 
    Car<U> car=new Car<U>();

    // We set the engine 
    car.setT(u);

    // We add the new car to the list of existing cars
    cars.add(car);
}
```

}

While i hope to have clarified the "two parameters" a bit more, above method is still "bad". Since we 'know' our 'U' will be of Type Engine we would want to have that specified directly by the method. However this is how you would use it:

```
 public class TestMe{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            GasEngine myGasEngine = new GasEngine();

            ArrayList<Car<Engine>> carlist = new ArrayList<Car<Engine>>();

            CarList.createCarWithEngineAndAddToCarList(myGasEngine, carlist);
        }
    }
```

Brb. Boss is here

Comment: @Terminator Then mark it as accepted (green checkmark). You can also upvote useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

`Car` itself is a generalized class - the `U` refers to it, not the `List`. `List<Car<U>>` should be interpreted as "List of Car of U".